# Simple understanding of completeness and decidability

Tags: logic

I'm trying to conceptualize these notions without requiring much mathematical maturity, somewhat informal, to get the gist. Could you let me know if there's anything incorrect in the following?

(1) A theory is **semantically complete** if all of its *logically true*(true in every interpretation) sentences, e.g. "A or not A", have a proof in the system.

(2) A theory is **syntactically complete** if all of its sentences are *logically true or false*(must be true or false in all interpretations from its axioms). If there are sentences that are true or false depending on interpretation, i.e. contingent truths, then the theory is syntactically incomplete.

(3) A theory is **decidable** if there is an algorithm to prove all of its logically true sentences and negations of logically false sentences, via having only a finite number of sentences or if there are an infinite number of sentences, finite number of them can be defined as axioms to entail all the sentences or their negations. If not, the theory is not decidable.

Comment: See [Completeness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic))

Comment: A "logic" is complete if it proves ALL valid formulas. A "theory", with non-logical axioms, is complete if it proves ALL logical consequences of the axioms.

Comment: 2 is wrong. See link above.